# How's the weather for hiking in lower Tibet in May?

Tags: china, weather-and-climate, hiking, tibet

I am considering doing [a hike](http://www.chinahighlights.com/travelguide/china-hiking/ganden-samye.htm) with a guide in **Tibet** from *Gandan Monastery* to *Samye Monastery* in **May**.

From what I've heard the temperatures during the **night** should be between **-5C and 10C** which is nothing extraordinary for the camping.

However I couldn't find any decent information about the precipitation. Could the Internet help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well the closest decent-sized town to all of this is Lhasa.  There is rain there of about 500mm (20 inches) annually, but most of that is in [July - September, and at night](http://www.chinahighlights.com/lhasa/weather.htm).  As such, for warmer months and to avoid the weather, May is the peak tourist season.

[Further down on the same link](http://www.chinahighlights.com/lhasa/weather.htm) it indicates that in May, the average precipitation is 1.1 inches (26mm) in May.  So next to nothing really, you'd be unlucky to get a lot of rain, if at all during the day.

The average temperatures according to that are from a low of 5C to average high of 19C, so potentially even better than you thought ;)

Comment: With over 1000m altitude amplitude over the hike, I'd be wary of generalizing climate information from one point. I guess it would tend to be drier higher up than in the valley?

Comment: I'm also wary of generalising, but I agree with the reasoning.